# How to improve Netbeans for ruby slow performance?

Tags: ruby, performance, netbeans

I am developing Ruby application with Netbeans because of its automatic code completion and its inline help system.

But when Netbeans try to autocomplete the source code while typing, the typing looks like stopped.

Is there any way to improve this experience? Maybe by disabling the code completion, inline help system, syntax highlighting, etc?

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the trade off of dynamically typed languages; since dynamic types make it harder (if not to impossible) to determine type when writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable extended type inference for methods (ie code completion -- showing what methods are available on an object) or rdoc (the inline help) from the NetBeans preferences.  These settings are found under the Miscellaneous tab, under Ruby, in the section labeled "Enable extended type inference".

You can disable syntax highlighting by removing the appropriate file associations.  This can be done under the Miscellaneous tab in the preferences, under "Files".

However you may consider exploring alternative editors or IDEs, as (depending upon which other features of the IDE you use or depend on) you may find that NetBeans is still slow and not providing much of an advantage over a simpler editor.  I have also found the performance of RubyMine to be better than NetBeans for ruby projects, and there's something to be said for using a tool thats designed from the bottom up for the job you're trying to accomplish.